# Django - how to reference paths of static files and can I use them in models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-staticfiles

I have a django model class with several images related to each instance. 
Those images follow a certain pattern and can be determined by the name field of the model.

Those Images reside within the project static files folder.

So I have written a method for my model class to generate file paths for the images. It searches the static files folder for all files that follow the pattern *.jpg (the asterisks is necessary, because the filename has incrementing numbers).
Once it has found a file it transforms the absolute filesystem path into an url that is passed to a view and template via a list.

```
def getImages(self)
  matches[]
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(
    os.listdir(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT_DIR,'images')), self.name + '*.jpg'):
    matches.append(
      os.path.join(settings.STATIC_URL, 'images', os.path.split(filename)[1]))
  return matches
```

This method works fine, but doesn't leave me quite satisfied. Here are the reasons:

- For development mode I am required to introduce a new variable called STATIC_ROOT_DIR, to obtain the path of the static files folder. I would like to use a consistent way to reference the static root folder for development and production. How can I achieve this? I would like to avoid development mode hackery as much as possible.
- I have to build a URL by joining the static_url path with other strings that will eventually make up the URL for this static file. Is there a better way to construct URLs? Maybe some library function?
- Last but not least: Is it good practice to do this in a model? Or is such a task better be done by a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to throw in another one: 
Using `STATIC_ROOT` will break if you host your files externally.

You can use the django-storage-backend yourself (untested, just written):

```
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from django.conf import settings

def getImages(self)
    static_storage = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
    directories, files = static_storage.listdir('images')
    return [
        static_storage.url('images/' + file) 
        for file in files 
        if file.startswith(self.name) and file.endswith('.jpg')
    ]
```

This will even return the correct URL if you use `CachedStaticFileStorage` or `S3BotoStorage` (from `django-storages`). And this will also be fine if you are in dev-mode.

Answer (score 3):

- There is a `STATIC_ROOT` variable in `settings.py`. Why not use it?
- Personally, I follow your way - just concatenating paths. But just found a function for that:

  ```
  from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
  print static('yourfile.jpg')
  ```

It works for me.

- I think model is a good place for it. You store files in filesystem like you store model data in database. In other words, both of these are examples of storage which is a model level thing.

Comment: I don't like using STATIC_ROOT here, because in production this path differs from development. Currently I am only using one settings file for development and production. I know it's not best practice.

Comment: You can import * from `development_settings.py` in your `settings.py`. And make `development_settings.py` available only on your dev host. For example, putting it into your VCS ignore list.